# MudBlazor DataGrid Column Headings not Bold

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I am using mudblazor 6.10.0. I have a MudDataGrid and everything works fine but the column headings are not bold like in the samples. I have the grid defined as follows

```
 <MudDataGrid T="Range" MultiSelection="true" FilterCaseSensitivity="DataGridFilterCaseSensitivity.CaseInsensitive" Items="@_carRanges" SortMode="SortMode.Multiple" Dense ="true"
             QuickFilter="@QuickFilter" ColumnResizeMode="@(ResizeMode.Column)" DragDropColumnReordering="true" Striped="true" FilterMode="DataGridFilterMode.ColumnFilterRow">
        <ToolBarContent>
            <MudTooltip Text="Add Range">
                <MudFab id="Add-CarRange" Color="Color.Tertiary" Size="Size.Medium" StartIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Add" Href="feerangesave/0" />
            </MudTooltip>
            <MudTextField @bind-Value="SearchString" Placeholder="Search" Adornment="Adornment.Start" Immediate="true"
                      AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Search" IconSize="Size.Medium" Class="mt-0"></MudTextField>
        </ToolBarContent>
        <Columns>
            <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Name" Title="name" Resizable="true" Filterable="true" />

            <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.MinRange" Title="Min Range" Resizable="true" Filterable="true" Format="N0" CellStyle="text-align: right"/>
            <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.MaxRange" Title="Max Range" Resizable="true" Filterable="true" Format="N0" CellStyle="text-align: right"/>
        </Columns>
    </MudDataGrid>
```

In the MainLayout.cs i have the following

```
 <MudDialogProvider/>
    <MudThemeProvider />
    <MudLayout>
        <MudAppBar Elevation="1" Dense="true" Color="MudBlazor.Color.Info">
            <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Menu" Edge="Edge.Start" OnClick="@ToggleDrawer" />
            <MudSpacer />
            <MudText Typo="Typo.h5" Color="MudBlazor.Color.Default" Style="color: white;">@Heading</MudText>
        </MudAppBar>
        <MudDrawer @bind-Open="@_menuOpen" ClipMode="_clipMode" Elevation="1" Variant="@DrawerVariant.Responsive">
            <NavMenu />
        </MudDrawer>
        <MudMainContent>
            <CustomErrorBoundary>
                <div class="content px-4">
                    @Body
                </div>
            </CustomErrorBoundary>
        </MudMainContent>
    </MudLayout>
```

[image: Here is the th being overridden]

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what is overriding the default CSS property. You could try replicating it using https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet or investigate the headers in the browser web deveveloper tools (Firefox).

Comment: .mud-table-root .mud-table-head .mud-table-cell {
  color: var(--mud-palette-text-primary);
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
} font-weight 500 is reponsible for the text being bold, you need to check what's overwritting it.

Comment: Hi @maciek yes i tried in in the snippet creator and it worked fine, good idea with the dev tools will try check it out and let you know

Comment: the th {  font-weight: bold;    text-align: -internal-center;} is being overridden by user agent stylesheet

Comment: The image you posted doesn't show what's overriding it, everything that's strikethrough  --- means that it isn't applied.

Comment: There is not much to go by to troubleshoot the problem. If it works in the snippet creator but does not work in your project there must be something within the project that overrides the default CSS. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always add styles to it manually with the `PropertyColumn.HeaderStyle` property.
i.e.

```html
<PropertyColumn Title="MyPos" HeaderStyle="font-weight:900;font-size:2rem;" Property="x => x.Position" />
```

Although, as @maciek mentions in the comments, you should try to find what's overriding your style first.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was because I had override the Default font with my own font. It appears that setting your own Default font, overrides all styles in the data grid.

To fix this, I set my custom fonts for each style (H1, H2, Body1, Body2 etc) and left the default alone.